# How do I suppress unnecessary response header output when running rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js, rspec

Whenever I run `rspec` I get the normal output for pass/fail but I also get a ton of unnecessary response headers output:

```
Edit Attributions on New Revision {}
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"=>"*", "Content-Type"=>"text/html; charset=utf-8", "ETag"=>"\"9c329e707f9c1df63471d37624dfe8c8\"", "Cache-Control"=>"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "X-Request-Id"=>"24bf9c7f-46b0-4301-8319-78c4fd50468d", "X-Runtime"=>"4.764758"}
{"Content-Type"=>"application/javascript", "Content-Length"=>"3895567", "Cache-Control"=>"public, must-revalidate", "Last-Modified"=>"Fri, 08 Apr 2016 23:26:12 GMT", "ETag"=>"\"d1d69d3e7c53ef21b4e9e217be43f514\"", "X-Request-Id"=>"973755fa-2186-4221-9364-e6971f1b2f1d", "X-Runtime"=>"0.003999"}
{"Content-Type"=>"text/css", "Content-Length"=>"639526", "Cache-Control"=>"public, must-revalidate", "Last-Modified"=>"Tue, 23 Feb 2016 21:19:37 GMT", "ETag"=>"\"7e0331f274e4ab0c18b5b92b460f39c3\"", "X-Request-Id"=>"8c171d01-2ae4-413d-9b64-7e215d268a4d", "X-Runtime"=>"0.007632"}
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"=>"*", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "ETag"=>"\"b6f5f42c017ec9fec3966e5eef76cfd6\"", "Cache-Control"=>"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "X-Request-Id"=>"659b3e90-afd3-4510-ac3f-06808b810af4", "X-Runtime"=>"0.079272"}
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"=>"*", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "ETag"=>"\"c3f68cb57b4c55f1b3ecbc25b791d065\"", "Cache-Control"=>"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "X-Request-Id"=>"e3d55d6c-f733-497e-b36d-564df307b1ca", "X-Runtime"=>"0.056954"}
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"=>"*", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "ETag"=>"\"4d3761c104bab6de73190c9197f4a37a\"", "Cache-Control"=>"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "X-Request-Id"=>"b80a6b8d-fb8f-4506-aa27-84569013acf8", "X-Runtime"=>"0.064435"}
{"Content-Type"=>"application/font-woff", "Content-Length"=>"65452", "Cache-Control"=>"public, must-revalidate", "Last-Modified"=>"Wed, 27 May 2015 06:45:14 GMT", "ETag"=>"\"33f308f01b7dd799ad6bc763e965e4ea\"", "X-Request-Id"=>"4916fd08-ceaf-4343-8208-bd4362115f1b", "X-Runtime"=>"0.025380"}
{"Content-Type"=>"application/font-woff", "Content-Length"=>"21956", "Cache-Control"=>"public, must-revalidate", "Last-Modified"=>"Thu, 11 Jun 2015 17:26:10 GMT", "ETag"=>"\"454550cee207f914914d902edf9dabaa\"", "X-Request-Id"=>"537cf7a0-df4b-4460-b054-2ff54553493f", "X-Runtime"=>"0.031455"}
{"Last-Modified"=>"Thu, 11 Jun 2015 17:26:10 GMT", "Content-Type"=>"image/vnd.microsoft.icon", "Cache-Control"=>"public, max-age=3600", "Content-Length"=>"0"}
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"=>"*", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "ETag"=>"\"f4f0390e08c4d6cabb0afafc458882b3\"", "Cache-Control"=>"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "Set-Cookie"=>"_specx_session=cG55d0ZSOG1pbG1SSXBBWDNLRDVNdWNyc3FtY2lHTlFDdXRuYzBQYSsvWDJVU1JsUGVxczJ3VDRBdzNOckxaNG9GMTJiVUZQTzR3cUs4N1JLQ3lDYlkraUN1S25EazdJeTI0eHFuWXJCOFJTMUxlZHhEMHRTZkxYOXdnZE1aV1FkeldlaFExOGhTSUU3SHBPeTh5UVhBPT0tLWk0d1owclVYMFdCNGZpV1NyUGxLWnc9PQ%3D%3D--f698eb7135d173d63ea808e6b8f7b9217ab259b5; path=/; HttpOnly", "X-Request-Id"=>"87dd1133-d8b4-4314-9afe-c1b091c55b3e", "X-Runtime"=>"0.080859"}
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"=>"*", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "ETag"=>"\"0e377127e31068f9b2be1405281bd1ce\"", "Cache-Control"=>"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "Set-Cookie"=>"_specx_session=cXZ1TTVtUTh2TFlWc1YzaVM2UXF0TXp5N21LZUJhMjdLOUtvVEpnQXNqd2dDaGxOdnRWK0VZd2xCRyswMDhGRTM1WU5rb01zdnBuUUZ6QUlmWnVCYVR0cm16dlgwY0F5WkhpMitKSjJ5YVZuT3ZzVWtpN2FvZ1ZMckVETFhibjNRQlc2K0VHNjBFK0FNNnVabXp6Z1FnPT0tLU45VzlwSitvTW4vOVdQcmxaWWFtVEE9PQ%3D%3D--738c68d84f121d52c7c48d3f9955cd49d2c5527c; path=/; HttpOnly", "X-Request-Id"=>"be6351eb-bacd-4f9a-98c2-8d31093d5c50", "X-Runtime"=>"0.015056"}
{"Content-Type"=>"application/font-woff", "Content-Length"=>"22656", "Cache-Control"=>"public, must-revalidate", "Last-Modified"=>"Thu, 11 Jun 2015 17:26:10 GMT", "ETag"=>"\"83e99827023b97285a3bf022e54725a7\"", "X-Request-Id"=>"2b1ab29f-e10e-4b2e-bc17-494e59e060f7", "X-Runtime"=>"0.035804"}
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"=>"*", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "ETag"=>"\"ab192391c442f53ceed96938f8a7f184\"", "Cache-Control"=>"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "Set-Cookie"=>"_specx_session=blVxM3NhVmUzZEtWbHdLSlBjZEtUVEJDWWJVOFlvRGxQeEdwaUtWNENsVkczQWFOT2FtMWZiaXh3bVJvSmtYUlgrQk5Qalp4OFNnRm1iTzI2RmZnejFxUENoeXl6NXZWRE5ZaTQ1Z2VBVHYxM3VoNFhkN3lkR09RcFBkWGtXZGMvY1RVdlNoYTlXcUdNS040WWJ3MC9nPT0tLTJ6bi9mZklKeWk1NENlUlVUbk9yY0E9PQ%3D%3D--94a48bb48f14e24840fd1ab6962c56700fd95ffe; path=/; HttpOnly", "X-Request-Id"=>"f4c52793-7bc1-4868-a43a-08fcf8f68ed1", "X-Runtime"=>"0.066712"}
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"=>"*", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "ETag"=>"\"ad15a8edc891daf72020469f46c48bbe\"", "Cache-Control"=>"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "Set-Cookie"=>"_specx_session=V0g1cTZxQ0RmMDVsVmdrRU1vQXpoSWFQRUhlWHRyWHowc05pN2FYTUs5WXlNL0NWRnRQZllIby9BUFhvdHJKcW94TEw5SHZQUVZoK3ZrTFlKQUZlRG5LNzBhT0FDa1BpVW9GKzFoUTFDTzlndXpnWis4RWdsTTVELzRGcGVhSjJhbHk2TndiTWpONXFrM3BBdWNhSEdBPT0tLUVQU1dQd0NqOWtpQjRUSHpGZWgzZEE9PQ%3D%3D--af42580e83d4b5c9773a4eb43b9518124ffdc573; path=/; HttpOnly", "X-Request-Id"=>"02acd844-22a6-4ec7-ad3e-75bb846b7d17", "X-Runtime"=>"0.019626"}
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"=>"*", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "ETag"=>"\"3f36ff1d7403fd570d4a3822756ff434\"", "Cache-Control"=>"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "Set-Cookie"=>"_specx_session=ZkVMT0F6aVJHZ1JkamdBbDVwL2sxVUd5aHA2MFpMSUI1TFFYRk5XTHNaam1za25tcVpYN2NuVG5mM1lEczB3cExadXp5MndzRHdKWGpGZTQ5bzQrYWJuYTk1OTltSFJjbFR4eHV0VEVTU0VLT3BucnFrenBaSzVWODJEMW5UaUFtMVpZRE40cmJkaG1Db25zSXZGVHpRPT0tLVdYRlpPdXhWR3lOS0FUVUJVQmoyREE9PQ%3D%3D--867fde5b418a331d6d30008671e7aa106fb48627; path=/; HttpOnly", "X-Request-Id"=>"e53be6fb-549e-4f33-a298-eabfc20faa68", "X-Runtime"=>"0.014555"}
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"=>"*", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "ETag"=>"\"0e8ed2b58acb96acc8068f0dd5d9435f\"", "Cache-Control"=>"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "Set-Cookie"=>"_specx_session=WFhJL0ZiVTBObW5DL2dISmVTYUxYSWR2TkpJakdXN0NNbVZ4RVRoZ1hpSEpMbG04ck42U2t0N1RnNUNTU2E3SEluaW9PeFNSZ2JRUGhudG5EOGFFL2NKaXZ2UEo0dzJrbkpwOUJEN3JyRFZ0K0dtckJxYnh2Y2VHcGJoV0VmTElxRVN3QTMyYnE4RmZUQnJmVFZQUlZnPT0tLUN5K1FvWXF4U0gvYlkxa2ZYRXY3S3c9PQ%3D%3D--508f0a36e3794f2b8acc08c7e0fea0cb5359e5c8; path=/; HttpOnly", "X-Request-Id"=>"413fcb8d-0db5-435c-8b94-f6f30a34bf78", "X-Runtime"=>"0.013824"}
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"=>"*", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "ETag"=>"\"2e233de31b494b2dd16e585a4364c3b1\"", "Cache-Control"=>"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "Set-Cookie"=>"_specx_session=djI4RjRBcnFjd3IvMXQ0M0NVS3plT1N0aGluOXJLODl6WUUxallnQWRJcDVLNjFYYVBHUnJObGVDUE5rWkthN25yUUE2S1B0RUFXRko2aXdUSGJ5V0lhUHJlUmNOMUgxQXBLK2UxRzBHbCtQNWRsZzJNbUZ6MFEyeXk4SzhQNUM2UkgzZ0YzTDhOcE15ejdOTnMzMWt3PT0tLUlIV1ZpMHJrbWhRdmJVdVd2WjFEZWc9PQ%3D%3D--893bf810f69f9b365b4bbef07de3e547af43aa09; path=/; HttpOnly", "X-Request-Id"=>"82b50261-8f66-4149-b3e9-8f5de2428015", "X-Runtime"=>"0.055278"}
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"=>"*", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "ETag"=>"\"68e23bd86c40278a555e02b15c033dfe\"", "Cache-Control"=>"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "Set-Cookie"=>"_specx_session=cG5EdjV3djNwdWw2T3JSbDU2d283dlNWaVN2VEJLUXRXV3J6bm5YRjVqYlY0WFRYRGZ1UzRmdDd4YnphZGFZYjBoWXBkdEJiYlN5UDJOUy9KRHNCazBmY082a2t1Z0JYQi94dUVmQjZRK1ZrY0V0bGFkQUZyblNQS3k1WDE2aHhQd3RVTHJNaTVOWHk0ZC9oS0NrWGpRPT0tLXRQTXhJRVdETHdNSDUyTFFnUXFWNUE9PQ%3D%3D--a09073e858e44b97fb2fa3cd6c750e69ac5884f6; path=/; HttpOnly", "X-Request-Id"=>"aed4bb2c-a85f-4b3a-9c2d-8c30f63f5ab6", "X-Runtime"=>"0.055204"}
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"=>"*", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "ETag"=>"\"357b2524442ed4c6fd97d3c7c2be0f13\"", "Cache-Control"=>"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "Set-Cookie"=>"_specx_session=MjM0c0lSblVBU3I4ZlN1bGtXVXVrbk9Lc05GSG9Od0xVZVA1UGd5OFExaW84TUt1OGVGK0N4aXRmVlF1dWNFUXJyREQ1cG16RHkyRFVHbVY5Ulc2MFlIWGRZL3ZKMDZZanc2dkRjdTlTa213ZXZyZk00VlZmUHpJWmVwV05tSHdlbXRqNG1HTkUwSDFOWkNUMG5PMFRnPT0tLXhRbnlDM2svczduellwQWtabUdiaFE9PQ%3D%3D--696be9321128bc91448cdab8f212ec2582ba95e9; path=/; HttpOnly", "X-Request-Id"=>"89e073a7-5c7f-477c-bbe1-7f7e1d69287d", "X-Runtime"=>"0.013037"}
{"Content-Type"=>"image/gif", "Content-Length"=>"1849", "Cache-Control"=>"public, must-revalidate", "Last-Modified"=>"Thu, 11 Jun 2015 17:26:10 GMT", "ETag"=>"\"edbb7d4b0a2c6e6d73a2396ad65fb277\"", "X-Request-Id"=>"bf515004-17e7-4f34-ab34-20f1a48abff2", "X-Runtime"=>"0.018488"}
<more of the same output here then the passing "." below>
.

Finished in 57.1 seconds
1 example, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 65368
```

None of my colleagues get this output and all our git ignored files are the same, so it must be a system setting I have.

Comment: Have you tried configuring RSpec `formatter`? Or running with `--format` option

Comment: @PetrGazarov yes - I got the same response header output even with different format

Comment: Odd, not common to see headers in test output and .gitignore entries shouldn't make any difference for rspec. Are you sure that all of your configuration/gem versions are the same?

Comment: @d_ethier I'm sure our gem versions are the same. There probably is some system level configuration that is different among our machines but I'm just not sure what that might be.

Comment: @FrederickCheung That was it! I used `gem pristine --all` so it restored all of them but the `capybara` gem was most likely the culprit. I must have modified it at some point and forgotten to revert.

Comment: @FrederickCheung can you post your comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find anything in your application/test code that might do this, one possibility is that one of the gems on your system has been edited (I've done that on occasion when debugging).

You can use the

```
gem pristine
```

command to reinstall a gem, or even `gem pristine --all` if you don't want to go to the effort of finding the culprit.